# Determine convergence or divergence of $ \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1 + \cos^2x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} dx$

Tags: real-analysis

> Determine convergence or divergence of $$ \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1 + \cos^2x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} dx$$

As the graph of the function suggests convergence, Let's find an upper bound that converges.

$$ \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1 + \cos^2x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} dx \leq
\int_0^{\infty} \frac{2}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} dx \leq
\int_0^{\infty} \frac{2}{x} dx$$

Given that $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{2}{x} dx $ diverges, i wont be able to show that the original converges.

What is my error? What upper bound could I choose?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Showing that there is an upper bound that diverges to $+\infty$ doesn't actually prove anything.  What we want is a lower bound:

$$x>1\implies\frac{1+\cos^2x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\ge\frac1{\sqrt{x^2+x^2}}=\frac{2^{-1/2}}x$$

And it seems you already know that $\int_0^\infty\frac1x~\mathrm dx$ diverges.

Comment: thx for the input. I am trying to understand. I was trying to find a upper bound that acutally converge as, when I graph the original function, it obviously shows convergence...

Comment: I do not believe convergence of such an integral should be obvious, especially since the integral diverges.

Answer (score 2):

Here it is an alternative approach:
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1+\cos^{2}(x)}{\sqrt{1+x^{2}}}dx \geq \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1+x^{2}}} = \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cosh(u)}{\sqrt{1+\sinh^{2}(u)}}du = \int_{0}^{\infty}du = +\infty
\end{align*}

Comment: You seem to be missing something in the last integral, unless $\int du$ is assumed to equal $\int1du$.

Comment: Perhaps it is not usual, but I meant the second option.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt given that I tend to think of differentials as being an actual object upon which multiplication can be defined (with some constraints of course) I tend to write it without a $1$ in front.

Comment: The notation $\int_S \mathrm{d}\mu = \mu(S)$ is common.

Comment: Ah, okay :-) ${} $

Answer (score 2):

**hint**
$$1+\cos^2 (x)\ge 1$$

$$\sqrt {1+x^2}\sim x \;(x\to +\infty) $$

Comment: so the integral diverges, but why, when graphing the function, it seems that it converges? trying to understanding.

Comment: it just seems but not.